# how to get data of nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple items with name `module_name`, and each of them have multiple input fields. Please see below:

```
<input type="hidden" value="slideshow" name="module_name[]">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_title[]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_info[]">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_title[]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_info[]">
```

I want to get all data when it is posted, so I'm trying this:

```
if(isset($_POST['module_name'])){

    foreach ($_POST['module_name'] as $k => $v) {       

        foreach ($_POST['slide_title'] as $key => $value) {

            $slide_title = addslashes($_POST['slide_title'][$key]);
            $slide_info = addslashes($_POST['slide_info'][$key]);

            $arr[] = array(
                    'slide_title' => $slide_title,
                    'slide_info' => $slide_info,

                );

        }

    }

    print_r($arr); //incorrect data

}
```

I want to get data of each module_name in an array, but with the above code I do not get correct data in the array, it displays the repeating data.

Comment: $_POST['module_name'] and $_POST['slide_title'] would be sibling elements. Are you sure you are doing that correctly there? Print out the data with echo'<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo'</pre>'; and then look over your code again, or paste the output of that for us so that we can check the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one `slide_title` and `slide_info` for one `module_name` i think you have to change your structure:

```
<input type="hidden" value="slideshow" name="module_name[1]">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_title[1][]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_info[1][]">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_title[1][]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_info[1][]">

...

<input type="hidden" value="slideshow" name="module_name[2]">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_title[2][]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_info[2][]">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_title[2][]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="slide_info[2][]">
```

So with this structure you can loop through your data like this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($_POST['module_name'] as $key => $value) {
    $data = array();
    foreach($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['slide_title'][$key]); $i++) {
        $data[] = array(
            "slide_title" => $_POST['slide_title'][$key][$i],
            "slide_info" => $_POST['slide_info'][$key][$i]
        );
    }
    $arr[$value] = $data;
}
```

An result would look like this:

```
"module_name_1" => array(
    array("slide_title" => "slide_title_1", "slide_info" => $slide_info_1),
    array("slide_title" => "slide_title_2", "slide_info" => $slide_info_2),
    array("slide_title" => "slide_title_3", "slide_info" => $slide_info_3)
),
"module_name_2" => array(
    array("slide_title" => "slide_title_1", "slide_info" => $slide_info_1),
    array("slide_title" => "slide_title_2", "slide_info" => $slide_info_2),
    array("slide_title" => "slide_title_3", "slide_info" => $slide_info_3)
)
...
```

You should notice, that this loop expect the same amount of `slide_title` and `slide_info` fields for each `module_name`.

I hope this is the desired result.